# How do I open a project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

That is, which file or folder in the workspace project folder? E.g. the equivalent of a `.csproj` file for a C# project and so forth. With the Android Studio projects I don't see any file that looks anything like a project file.

Note: I am not asking specifically which file, name and all, as that differs for each project, unless the 'project file' keeps the same name all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There are `build.gradle` files. AndroidStudio auto-detects these, and any changes to them.
There is usually one main "build.gradle" for the entire project, and one for each module you have in your project. You usually need to edit the "build.gradle" in your module folder (for example, to add library dependencies). In a new project you usually have 1 module, called "app".

There are some other less important files, such as "project_name.iml", which you never need to edit. (At least I never needed to)

Comment: Whoa, I don't want to get into hand editing these files yet. I just wanted to know which one to double-click when opening a project, but it looks like `build.gradle` is the one?

Comment: @ProfK I'm not sure about clicking on these files to open a project, I never tried that. These are the most important files in a project, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio does not have a project file, but it can open **any** type of file **and the project** that it is in. So I usually create a new, empty text file in the root of my Android project and call it "###.android-project". I double click on this file and Windows, correctly, asks me how I want to open it. I select "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe".

Then Android Studio opens, and asks me the first time how I want to open this file. I tell it, that it is a text file. Then it opens it as a text file, **and the project**, and remembers that it is a text file, and will not ask me again. I quickly close this text file, and I have the project open, exactly as if I had opened it from the "File->Open Project" menu.

I could keep project notes in this file, but I usually leave it empty. It does not matter, because Android Studio does not use it for anything.